# Stream to String in Jdom

Tags: java, jdom

How to preserve white space in jdom?

i get the below error:

`org.jdom.JDOMException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog`

This is my code, kindly tell the solution for this code...

```
import org.jdom.*;
import org.jdom.input.*;
import org.jdom.output.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class JDOM_XML_TEST {
    Document m_doc = null;
    public Element elmEHResponse = null;
    String sEHResponseXml = "";
    String sOperationType = "Edit";
    static String s_return = "";
    StringBuffer strbuffer = null;
    String sParamsXml_1 = "<VWPortal>" + "<EHResponse Type='" + "  test    CustomObject" + "' ProgLangId='" + "1" + "'>" + "<Signature>public void Item1_ButtonClick_RESP1(Context ObjContextParam, string sPortlet, string sPortletInstanceId, CILPrtlDataset objCILPrtlDataset)</Signature></EHResponse><ResultType>Result</ResultType></VWPortal>";
    //String sParamsXml ="public String   Display_Test(){"     "String s ='Welcome';"    "return s;      }";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDOM_XML_TEST xml_test = new JDOM_XML_TEST();
        s_return = xml_test.getXml();
        //System.out.println("Value is:::"+s_return);   
    }

    public String getXml() {
        try {
            if (!sOperationType.equalsIgnoreCase("Delete")) {
                SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
                //Commended for CustomObject
                //doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sParamsXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

                //For CustomObject Alignment
                strbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                strbuffer.append("public String   Display_Test(){ \n");
                strbuffer.append("\t\t\tString s ='Welcome'; \n");
                strbuffer.append("\t\t\t return s;  \n");
                strbuffer.append("}");

                sEHResponseXml = strbuffer.toString();
                System.out.println("Value of sEHResponseXml:::" + sEHResponseXml);

                builder.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                m_doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sEHResponseXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                elmEHResponse = m_doc.getRootElement();

                System.out.println("Value of elmEHResponse in before:::" + elmEHResponse);
                XMLOutputter Out = new XMLOutputter();
                sEHResponseXml = Out.outputString(elmEHResponse);

                System.out.println("Value of elmEHResponse in after:::" + sEHResponseXml);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sEHResponseXml;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some code/xml if you want an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to preserving whitespace in your XML but some extra bytes before the start of your xml content. Use NotePad++ (or BBEdit etc) and check if there any extra characters at the start of your xml doc. Also post your XML here.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, kindly tell the solution for this code...

```
import org.jdom.*;
import org.jdom.input.*;
import org.jdom.output.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class JDOM_XML_TEST {
    Document m_doc = null;
    public Element elmEHResponse = null;
    String sEHResponseXml = "";
    String sOperationType = "Edit";
    static String s_return = "";
    StringBuffer strbuffer = null;
    String sParamsXml_1 = "<VWPortal>" + "<EHResponse Type='" + "  test    CustomObject" + "' ProgLangId='" + "1" + "'>" + "<Signature>public void Item1_ButtonClick_RESP1(Context ObjContextParam, string sPortlet, string sPortletInstanceId, CILPrtlDataset objCILPrtlDataset)</Signature></EHResponse><ResultType>Result</ResultType></VWPortal>";
    //String sParamsXml ="public String   Display_Test(){"     "String s ='Welcome';"    "return s;      }";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDOM_XML_TEST xml_test = new JDOM_XML_TEST();
        s_return = xml_test.getXml();
        //System.out.println("Value is:::"+s_return);   
    }

    public String getXml() {
        try {
            if (!sOperationType.equalsIgnoreCase("Delete")) {
                SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
                //Commended for CustomObject
                //doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sParamsXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

                //For CustomObject Alignment
                strbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                strbuffer.append("public String   Display_Test(){ \n");
                strbuffer.append("\t\t\tString s ='Welcome'; \n");
                strbuffer.append("\t\t\t return s;  \n");
                strbuffer.append("}");

                sEHResponseXml = strbuffer.toString();
                System.out.println("Value of sEHResponseXml:::" + sEHResponseXml);

                builder.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                m_doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sEHResponseXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                elmEHResponse = m_doc.getRootElement();

                System.out.println("Value of elmEHResponse in before:::" + elmEHResponse);
                XMLOutputter Out = new XMLOutputter();
                sEHResponseXml = Out.outputString(elmEHResponse);

                System.out.println("Value of elmEHResponse in after:::" + sEHResponseXml);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sEHResponseXml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that in your code you are creating a StringBuffer `strbuffer`

```
            //For CustomObject Alignment
            strbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            strbuffer.append("public String   Display_Test(){ \n");
            strbuffer.append("\t\t\tString s ='Welcome'; \n");
            strbuffer.append("\t\t\t return s;  \n");
            strbuffer.append("}");
```

This StringBuffer has the contents

```
public String   Display_Test(){ 
            String s ='Welcome'; 
            return s;  
}
```

You are assigning that StringBuffer to the String `sEHResponseXml` and printing it to the console

```
            sEHResponseXml = strbuffer.toString();
            System.out.println("Value of sEHResponseXml:::" + sEHResponseXml);
```

The problem is that the String `sEHResponseXml` ***does not*** contain valid it XML (it is not XML at all). You then try and construct a JDOM document `m_doc` from this string

```
            builder.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
            m_doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sEHResponseXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

And this is where you program fails, telling you

`org.jdom.JDOMException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog`

I re-ran your program but changed `strbuffer` to contain valid XML (`<doc> <p> h1 </p> </doc>`), here is the program below

```
import org.jdom.*;
import org.jdom.input.*;
import org.jdom.output.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class JDOM_XML_TEST {
    Document m_doc = null;
    public Element elmEHResponse = null;
    String sEHResponseXml = "";
    String sOperationType = "Edit";
    static String s_return = "";
    StringBuffer strbuffer = null;
    String sParamsXml_1 = "<VWPortal>" + "<EHResponse Type='" + "  test    CustomObject" + "' ProgLangId='" + "1" + "'>" + "<Signature>public void Item1_ButtonClick_RESP1(Context ObjContextParam, string sPortlet, string sPortletInstanceId, CILPrtlDataset objCILPrtlDataset)</Signature></EHResponse><ResultType>Result</ResultType></VWPortal>";
    //String sParamsXml ="public String   Display_Test(){"     "String s ='Welcome';"    "return s;      }";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDOM_XML_TEST xml_test = new JDOM_XML_TEST();
        s_return = xml_test.getXml();
        //System.out.println("Value is:::"+s_return);   
    }

    public String getXml() {
        try {
            if (!sOperationType.equalsIgnoreCase("Delete")) {
                SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
               //Commended for CustomObject
               //doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sParamsXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

                //For CustomObject Alignment
                strbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                strbuffer.append("<doc> <p> h1 </p> </doc>");


                sEHResponseXml = strbuffer.toString();
                System.out.println("Value of sEHResponseXml:::" + sEHResponseXml);

                builder.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                m_doc = builder.build(new ByteArrayInputStream(sEHResponseXml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                elmEHResponse = m_doc.getRootElement();

                System.out.println("Value of elmEHResponse in before:::" + elmEHResponse);
                XMLOutputter Out = new XMLOutputter();
                sEHResponseXml = Out.outputString(elmEHResponse);

                System.out.println("Value of elmEHResponse in after:::" + sEHResponseXml);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sEHResponseXml;
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
Value of sEHResponseXml:::<doc> <p> h1 </p> </doc>
Value of elmEHResponse in before:::[Element: <doc/>]
Value of elmEHResponse in after:::<doc> <p> h1 </p> </doc>
```